# Laravel 5 - Nest Resource index method resource ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, nested-resources

I try to make a default controller base on the [Laravel Restful Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers), and I'm block with the `index` method with `Nested Resources`.

I have a route `Route::resource('photos.comments', 'DefaultController');` and I need to get the `photo_id` in my `index` method. But so fare, I only get `{photos}`.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // $request->route('photos) => {photos}
}
```

or

```
public function index(Request $request, $photosId)
{
    // photosId => {photos}
}
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you're doing it right. What do you mean when you say you get `{photos}`? Is the `photo_id` in the URL? Like `photos/1/comments`?

Here's how I do it and it works:

route.php

```
Route::resource('users.stuff' ,'StuffController');
```

StuffController.php

```
public function index($uid, Request $request)
{
    //$uid contains the user id that is in the URL
    User::find($uid)->doSomeStuff();
    dd($uid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your example and I get the same result. When I print `$uid`  I get `{photos}` instead of the excepted value `1`.

Comment: How is your URL? How are you redirecting to the page that has the nested resource?

Comment: As always, it was a stupid mistake. I just checked how I was generated my route to answer you, when I found out that I forgot to set my `photos` id in my route -_- Thanks for your answers !